# Перебор id пользователей для отправки сообщения для бота вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Пишу бота для вк на vk_api. И столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу перебрать id пользователей для массовой рассылки. Пробовал перебор в разные места вставлять, но без успешно.

```
def rassilka(message):
    with open('all.txt', 'r') as f:
        for i in f:
            user_id = f.readline(int(i))

            vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': 0})
```

При вызове функции выдает ошибку

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: you should specify peer_id, user_id, domain, chat_id or user_ids param
```

Читал в интернете про данную ошибку, но все без успешно. Ничего не помогло

В файле **all.txt** хранятся id пользователей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
with open('all.txt', 'r') as file:
    users = file.readlines()
for user in users:
    vk.method(
        'messages.send', 
        {'user_id': int(user), 
        'message': message, 
        'random_id': 0}
    )
```

Comment: выдает ошибку **vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: user_id not integer**

Comment: Исправил ответ, попробуйте (user_id передавался как строка, vk нужно было число)

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)